# Why won't my flex items align side-by-side?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why won't my .summary and img items align next to each other? I have a div section with class="resume-container" containing three items. The first item "contact-info" should stretch the whole width of the screen, the second and 3rd items, summary and img, should be set side-by-side under the first item each taking up half the available screen space. I chose to use flex to make the site adaptable to differing screen sizes. Is there a better way to do this?

```css
.resume-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 0.5%;
}

.contact-info {
  background-color: #206977ad;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: .4rem;
  padding-top: 0.1rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.1rem;
  margin-bottom: .8%;
  align-self: center;
  flex-grow: 2;
  align-self: stretch;
  min-width: 95%;
}

.summary {
  max-width: 45%;
  background-color: #a1cd6c91;
  padding-right: .7em;
  padding-left: .7em;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.summary p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-container img {
  max-width: 45%;
  margin-left: 0.8%;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="resume-container">
  <div class="contact-info">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="summary">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="Picture not Found">
  </div>
```

Output
[image]

I want the summary section and img to appear inline with each other. Why doesn't this happen?

Comment: Welcome on SO , i turned your codes into a snippet, you may add fake image and fake text to reproduce your behavior ;)  Also mind padding,width,margin,borders,gap all together to be less than 100% ;)  box-sizing can be helpfull too.

Comment: Judging by the demo above, it _does_ lay out like your diagram suggests.

Comment: The image is a screenshot of how it shouldn't look. The red arrow indicating where the image should be instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet shows them literally next to each other (given the viewport size).

On a big screen, the `summary` is next to `contact` because `contact` is only 95% wide. This is because of the `max-width: 95%`. `summary` has no real width declared thats why it slips up. Its (non existing) content fits in there. Declaring only a `max-width` on `summary` and `img-container` doesn't set a real width, it just tells "not further than this".

Give proper widths to your containers.

Regarding the width: when you have 50/50 and add margins, apply them evenly to the inner sides, to make it truly centered. You then also have to subtract the width of the margin from the width of the containers, otherwise they will be bigger than 50%.

I suggest for mobile screens to change add a media query where the direction of the flex is set to `column` (standard is `row`) and make the containers 100% width.

See all in snippet below:

```css
.resume-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 0.5%;
}

.contact-info {
  background-color: #206977ad;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: .4rem;
  padding-top: 0.1rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.1rem;
  margin-bottom: .8%;
  
  /* new */
  width: 100%;
}

/* new */
.summary,
.img-container {
  width: calc(50% - 0.4%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.summary {
  background-color: #a1cd6c91;
  padding-right: .7em;
  padding-left: .7em;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  
  /* new */
  margin-right: 0.4%;
}

.summary p {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-container {
  border-radius: 2rem;
  
  /* new */
  margin-left: 0.4%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* new */
.img-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

/* new */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .resume-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .summary,
  .img-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="resume-container">
  <div class="contact-info">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="summary">
    <p>Damage report? Sections 27, 28 and 29 on decks four, five and six destroyed. Without our shields, at this range it is probable a photon detonation could destroy the Enterprise.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://www.buzzfeed.de/bilder/2017/09/18/90143589/24703335-buzzfeed-de.png" alt="Make it so">
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved the issue. I'm still very new to this, but it's helpful to learn that even when you want your sizing to be responsive, you still need to set a "real width" as you put it. 

I appreciate your time and explanation.

Comment: I recommend [https://flexboxfroggy.com/](https://flexboxfroggy.com/) If you want to dig deeper into flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex-shrink: 1;` to both containers that should be next to each other to allow them to shrink if necessary.